# Listen to incoming webhooks with Mautic (external email provider)

Tags: php, symfony, webhooks, email, mautic

I have an email provider (Pepipost) that is able to trigger a webhook (post to provided address) each time the mail is opened, bounced etc. So they provide a response of your sent messages status.

The webhook format is [described here](https://pepipost.readme.io/docs/what-are-the-different-webhooks-format)

How should I listen to them in my private Mautic install? Could point me to the right direction, where to search (API or should I create a form...)

UPDATE:
It seems that I have to create a web-hook in Mautic using API... But I failed to find any document to start with. How Mautic trigers it's internal statistics for emails?

Comment: What do you mean by "private" intsall?

Comment: I mean it is not a cloud based, it is installed on my private server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pr in the Mautic git repository if you so desire, so as to get it working with webhooks. The link to the PR is [here](https://github.com/mautic/mautic/pull/7480). What you can do is merge this branch with your current Mautic version or you can make the changes manually, but do this with a fresh install. If you have certain setup up and running you can take the backup of the database and then migrate to the new installation after the changes have been done.

1. To do that download or clone the Mautic repository
2. Make changes as per the PR.
3. And follow the usual Mautic setup. You can use this [link](https://pepipost.com/tutorials/tag/mautic/) for reference.
4. You won't need to set up the custom SMTP parameters since it will be auto-populated in the ESP list named **Pepipost - SMTP**. Just select this and enter your SMTP login credentials while setting it up.
5. Set webhook link in the Pepipost dashboard to be http://www.mautic-installation-domain-name.com/mailer/pepipost/callback and you are good to go.